# How to Insert an Interactive Menu into Python Turtle Graphics

Tags: menu, python-2.7, python-idle, turtle-graphics, cheeseshop

So I have an assignment in Computer Science that requires that I put an interactive menu into my python turtle graphics projects. I run on python 2.7.3 and would like some help on what modules to import and a basic outline of how to put an interactive menu into python turtle graphics. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

In 3.x, look at Lib/turtledemo/**main**.py for how to put a turtle canvas into a tkinter window with other stuff.  In 2.x, the turtledemo main code is in Demo/turtle/turtleDemo.py in the source repository, but the Demo directory is not installed on Windows.